# Printing from ASP.Net Server

Tags: asp.net, printing

I have found lots of examples on the internet and none of them do anything. No error, no print, just completes code and that is it.

What I want to do (for phase 1) is to print a document that is one the IIS server, from the IIS Server, using the ASP.Net application.

I say this because i think many of the examples I have gotten into might be for windows and or it might be assuming I want to print to the clients local printer. No, I want to print anywhere in any fashion but in a web application for a start.

here is a sample of what I am doing nearly exactly.

```
    Dim infoPrint As New ProcessStartInfo()
    infoPrint.Verb = "print"
    infoPrint.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    infoPrint.FileName = "C:\Temp\MyFile.txt"
    infoPrint.UseShellExecute = True
    infoPrint.Arguments = "\" & printername & "\"
    Process.Start(infoPrint)
```

I have tried various different printer syntax like removing the \ etc.
I have tried print, Print, PrintTo and printto
It doesnt generate an error it just does nothing but it does run the code

Another example of what I tried (which is basically the same) is the code within the answer in this forum link
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/10a08e00-0c17-4223-868b-30b1df7b6d1a/printer-for-pdf-using-systemdiagnosticsprocessstartinfo?forum=vbgeneral

again does nothing, no error just runs the code. I should point out that yes I have been able to manually print to the printer I am trying to code print to.

I have also tried this exact code and in the settings object I can see everything appears to be correct. Correct printer, correct file path etc

```
    Dim printjob As New Process
    printjob.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Temp\MyFile.txt"
    printjob.StartInfo.Verb = "Print"
    printjob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    printjob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    Dim settings As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
    settings.PrintFileName = "C:\Temp\MyFile.txt"
    settings.PrinterName = PrinterList(2) 'this is a custom method that is returning the correct string
    settings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    printjob.Start()
```

Comment: There's really not any difference printing from a server than there is from any other .NET application running on a client's PC. Perhaps you should show what you've tried in your question.

Comment: ah yes sorry I have added a sample